# "Burn in" a global variable on function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the way to "burn in" an external variable to a function upon definition?

```
funcs = []
for n in range(5):
    def f(x):
        return n * x
    funcs.append(f)

del n
```

But trying

```
[g(2) for g in funcs]
```

or

```
funcs[1](2)
```

Gives an error

```
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Is there a way to allow defining a function with a parameter which will become fixed for the function scope?

Comment: Your code works fine as written, although, you are probably not generating the functions you think you are due to the lexical scoping of python closures (n will be the value `n` had in the scope the functions were defined, i.e. `n == 4` for all the functions in `funcs`

Comment: Wait, did you explicitely `del n`??? That isn't what was there originally...

Comment: Try this `g=lambda x:[n*x for n in range(5)]` `g(2)`

Comment: @McGrady why? The code works fine as written... except for the `del n` which was added by an edit...